# how to trim leading zero in oracle sql from concatenation text (text:number-number-number

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace, leading-zero

> how to trim leading zero in oracle sql from concatenation text
> (text:number-number-number)
>
> example(word:number-number-number) word can have text or double zero
> but always has char before it after word, max digits separated by '-'
> all time max 3 digits i want to keep zeros in first part. and after
> that if remove leading 0 in sequence but keep it if it's only one 0
>
> MachineAbc00:1-0-03  = MachineAbc00:1-0-3
> MachineAbc00:1-001-02  = MachineAbc00:1-1-2
>
> tried many combination, not successful , like

---

### REGEXP_REPLACE  ('MachineO00:1-0-03*', '0+(?!$)', '-')
REGEXP_REPLACE  ('MTROPQFMO00:1-0-03*', '(-0){1,}', '-')

Answer (score 0):

If all the input strings are in the exact format you said they are, then something like this should work:

```
with
  sample_strings (str) as (
    select 'MachineAbc00:1-0-03'      from dual union all
    select 'MachineAbc00:1-001-02'    from dual union all
    select 'MachineZzzyx:200-020-002' from dual union all
    select 'machineCX032:0-000-0'     from dual
  )
select str as old_str,
       regexp_replace(str, '([:-])0*(\d+)', '\1\2') as new_str
from   sample_strings
;

OLD_STR                  NEW_STR                 
------------------------ ------------------------
MachineAbc00:1-0-03      MachineAbc00:1-0-3      
MachineAbc00:1-001-02    MachineAbc00:1-1-2      
MachineZzzyx:200-020-002 MachineZzzyx:200-20-2   
machineCX032:0-000-0     machineCX032:0-0-0
```

The regular expression function finds any occurrence of (colon or dash) followed by (zero or more `0` characters/digits) followed by at least one more digit. The "zero or more `0` digits" is maximal with the property that there must be at least one more digit AFTER that match (even if that extra digit hapens to be a zero - see my last test string, which I added precisely in order to test that this works correctly). The function replaces each such occurrence with the first and third fragments, removing the middle one (the zeros you must remove from your string). The references `\1` and `\2` refer to the first and the second parenthesized sub-expressions - the punctuation mark (colon or dash) and, respectively, the final digits (excluding the leading zeros that must be removed).